# (Nginx+Passenger) Rails running Threads get killed when used along with passenger_max_requests setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

My Nginx+Passenger settings are the following:

```
passenger_max_pool_size 6;
passenger_max_requests 600;
```

And in my Rails Controller i use threads to do excel imports in the following manner:

```
t = Thread.new do
 @json_response = Import::Admin.create_admin_user params
end
```

The problem that i encounter is after the process serves 600 requests (which is the limit set to avoid memory leaks) it shuts down the process even if the above mentioned thread is alive and running on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Threads incorrectly, server won't wait for a Thread to finish. If you need to perform heavy weight calculations, use background jobs. For example ActiveJob with Sidekiq.